# ADB Error: device not found USB

Tags: android, adb, device

i tried connect my 7` tab (KrugerKM0793) by USB.

I uninstalled all USB drivers and re-installed them from `sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`.

After this the device manager found an "Android ADB Interface". 
There were no errors. But it seems Eclipse cannot see ADB.

I checked ADB.exe and this is my log:

```
C:\Android_SDK\sdk\platform-tools>adb usb
error: device not found

C:\Android_SDK\sdk\platform-tools>adb kill-server

C:\Android_SDK\sdk\platform-tools>adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *

C:\Android_SDK\sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
```

I tried to find a solution but all write to install new APK but I cannot install adb wireless-root problem.

Comment: Probably not your problem, but make sure your device has "USB Debugging" enabled - http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Comment: USB Debugging is enabled.

Comment: SOLVED
what i do:

C:\Users\MyName\.android\adb_usb.ini and inside add

    # ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
    # USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
    # 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.
    0x2207

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to find a solution but all write to install new APK but I
>   cannot install adb wireless-root problem.

Installing a new APK seems a weird solution, APK's are installed on mobile devices.

Just to be clear, the problem is Eclipse cannot find adb?

Don't you mean re-installing Android SDK?, this could work.

Also update android SDK tools and platform toold through your Android SDK manager.

Comment: APK Debugging by WIFI, my problem is adb cannot find device but Device Manager can. I will try re-installing Android SDK but I think this does not help.

Comment: Oh ok, you say Eclipse cannot see ADB. But you mean ADB cannot see device.

Comment: Try updating Google USB drivers through your SDK manager and restarting adb. Also remove faulty device from device manager.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install Adb driver installer it will search for devices and install any missing drivers

http://adbdriver.com/downloads/

It worked for me problem fixed straight away :)

Answer (score 0):

for what it's worth i've been up to my ears with this problem and my fix turned out to be to stop using a USB HUB on my desk, and to plug the android device directly into one of the USB ports on my motherboard

Symptom: USB Not Found in DDMS, Intllij.
adb devices would list my device and then lose it.

'twas the usb hub